# Convert Boolean to Integer in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

Take the following code:

```
Sub Main()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim b As Boolean

    i = 1
    b = i
    i = b
    Console.WriteLine(i)

    i = Convert.ToInt32(b)
    Console.WriteLine(i)

End Sub
```

This prints the following:

```
-1
1
```

Why is this?

(Just a joke :) You can get 0 too...

```
Int32.TryParse("True", i)
Console.WriteLine(i)
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

What you're seeing is a bit of legacy code showing its head.

At the heart of the matter is the VT_BOOL type. Visual Basic 6.0 used the VT_BOOL type (AKA VARIANT_BOOL) for its boolean values. True for a VARIANT_BOOL is represented with the value VARIANT_TRUE which has the integer value -1. During the conversion to [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) it was decided that when using Visual Basic conversion routines to convert a boolean value to an Integer value, Visual Basic 6.0 semantics would be maintained on the return value; it would be -1.

The first implicit conversion occurs with the b = i line. Under the hood this does an implicit conversion from integer to boolean. Any non-zero value is deemed to be true, therefore the resulting value is true.

However, the following line of code is doing an implicit conversion to an integer type.

```
i = b
```

Under the hood this uses one of the Visual Basic conversion routines ([CType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4x2877xb%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) or [CInt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fctcwhw9%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)) to convert the value to an integer. As such Visual Basic semantics are in play and the value returned is -1.

The next interesting line is the `Convert.ToInt32()` line. This is using a .NET conversion routine which does not use Visual Basic semantics. Instead, it returns the underlying [BCL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_Class_Library) representation for a true boolean value which is 1.

Comment: You might want to add some about about WHY VT_BOOL was used, and why it's value is -1.

VB 6 only had 1 set of "and" and "or" operators, that did both logical and bitwise operations (most languages have 2 sets).

This worked by making "and" implemented as "&" and have the literal default to -1.

Comment: That way "true and x" is non zero anytime "x" is non zero.

Comment: You can get a sense of the "why" in my answer to a mostly-unrelated question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46331671/3043

Comment: And how does this explain why the compiler seems to be doing this for converting a bool to an int: `-(b > false)`?

Answer (score 33):

Some languages consider boolean true to be -1 rather than 1.  I'd have to do research to see why, as I don't recall.

In VB6, the constant `True` has the value `-1`.

However, `Convert.ToInt32(Boolean)` is [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cew9dz7.aspx) as returning "The number 1 if value is true; otherwise, 0."  That way, it's the same no matter which framework language you're using.

Edit: See the question [boolean true -- positive 1 or negative 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/727196/boolean-true-positive-1-or-negative-1)

Comment: Some languages use `-1` as `True`, because it is `0b11111111`, so every bit is the opposite of zero's binary representation, such that using a bitwise NOT operation on one would result in the other.

Comment: In .NET 4.0 you get `CInt(true) = -1` and `Convert.Int32(true) = 1`

Answer (score 12):

As to why -1 is used for True, I believe that it's because it is literally (NOT 0).

Start with zero, flip all the bits and then read it as two's complement--comes out negative one.

So since anything that is not False is True, and False is 0, the (NOT False) is represented by -1.

This may be just coincidence, though....

Comment: That's exactly why VB uses -1 for True. :)

Comment: +1.  It's interesting to note that if "true" is -1, the same operators can be used for Boolean logic and integer bit-masking.  It's also interesting to note that the question of whether to short-circuit "and" and "or" is independent of the question of whether 'true' operands should be forced to a single value.

Answer (score 8):

From MSDN Visual Basic documentation:

[Type Conversions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wts33hb3.aspx)

> When Visual Basic converts numeric
>   data type values to Boolean, 0 becomes
>   False and all other values become
>   True. When Visual Basic converts
>   Boolean values to numeric types, False
>   becomes 0 and True becomes -1.

And for [Convert.ToInt32(value)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa325172(VS.71).aspx):

> retuns the number 1 if value is true;
>   otherwise, 0.

So for your code:

```
i = 1
b = i // b becomes true
i = b // true = -1
Console.WriteLine(i)  // i is -1

i = Convert.ToInt32(b)  // Convert.ToInt32(true) = 1
Console.WriteLine(i)    // i is 1
```

Comment: Add a link for those doc quotes and I'll upmod.

Answer (score 3):

That's because in [VB.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET), Boolean values are -1 for true and 0 for false by default.  I am not sure why it prints as 1 the second time, though...

Answer (score 2):

"True" is an negation from the 0 value of a numeric data type!

Not(0) for non-signed types returns 1.

Not(0) for signed types returns -1.

I don't know your code, maybe your code performs a internal data conversion the second time.

Answer (score 2):

This is a dodgy answer but:

```
    Dim b As Boolean
    b = False
    Dim i As Integer
    i = IIf(b, 1, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

All numeric data types can used as Boolean! The result is dependent on the used data type.

Examples:

```
Dim i As Byte    ' Byte is non-signed!
Dim b As Boolean = True

i = b            ' Set first (lowest) bit of i (non-signed byte)
' i is now binary 0000 0001 = 1!


Dim i As SByte   ' SByte is signed!
Dim b As Boolean = True

i = b            ' Set all bits of i (signed byte)
' i is now FF (binary 1111 1111 = -1 !
```

Integer is signed, True to Integer -> -1.

UInteger is non-signed, True to UInt -> 1.

And so on...

A false value clears the highest bit in signed numerics, and lowest in non-signed numerics.

Therefore False is 0 in all numeric data types.