# Named numbers as variables

Tags: c#, c++, conventions

I've seen this a couple of times recently in *high profile* code, where constant values are defined as variables, named after the value, then used only once. I wondered why it gets done?

E.g. Linux Source (resize.c)

```
unsigned five = 5;
unsigned seven = 7;
```

E.g. C#.NET Source (Quaternion.cs)

```
double zero = 0;
double one = 1;
```

Comment: To me, this sounds like people taking the "avoid hardcoding numbers" guideline a bit too far. In almost all circumstances, it's better to use predefined constants so that you can easily change each occurrence of a number later on. But naming them after their content seems like a terrible idea.

Comment: I think if you examine the code of resize.c, you will find that those numbers are not constants, but will in fact be set to all the different powers of five and seven lower than the end value, as the backups are iterated through.

Comment: Just saw that Buddy, and commented further down here, but thanks, I was looking naively at that code, and after a harder look I saw that they were passed by reference to another call.

Comment: Whenever `five` changes it's meaning to say `7` or something else, you'd only have to change it in one place. ;) Sarcasm aside: This is taking "avoid hardcoded/magic numbers" a step or two too far.

Comment: So in fact `five` and `seven` have *bad* naming and the name would reflect that it is to represent a powerOf .. . (Note though that there are not marked `const`)...

Comment: Maybe they're following the guide to write unmaintainable code?  https://www.thc.org/root/phun/unmaintain.html (under "Miscellaneous Techniques", bullet #18)

Comment: You mean just in case that five one day is redefined to mean 6?

Comment: This is not what you are asking, but a common "named number" is `PI`. Because it's impractical (and perhaps impossible) to include the exact value of π in code, an approximation is used. Now it becomes reasonable to make it a constant - to explicitly define the approximation you chose, in one place, where it can easily be changed if another approximation is later desired. Although the pedant would say that most libraries should call it `APPROXIMATE_VALUE_OF_PI` instead of `PI` - it's not actually π, after all.

Comment: @LeeWhite and everyone arguing the "simple guideline taken too far" explanation: I am a bit skeptical of this. Is *every* instance of named number constants like these an error? Is there no legitimate reason for it (at least with integers)?

Comment: @Superbest: The example given by the OP is not an error. However, it seems like overkill to assig `5` to a variable named `five`. But if you have a `for`-loop and it needs to be looping a specified amount of times, it would be good practice (and easier to maintain) to set this specific amount in a good named constant. Then, whenever the specification changes, you can simply change the value of the constant.

Comment: No one would be surprised to see *constants* handled in this way -- it seems the spirit of the OP question is, why would this be done with a *variable*?  One speculation: maybe the developer moves between languages and is more familiar with a language that doesn't have true constants (like Python or PHP), and is declaring a variable that in practice is used like a constant.

Comment: @ChrisJohnson I personally would be very surprised to see constants handled in this way. Ok I wouldn't be suprised, but it would lead me to question the organisation that wrote it (often the developers are just following a foolish coding standard)

Comment: These numbers do not represent the numbers 5 and 7 in the linux kernel. Read the docs!  (Hint, the previous line has `three = 1` )

Comment: Many are criticizing the code without reading it. Go read the code. If you can't understand it, then explain how the variable names impeded your comprehension.

Comment: Not saying it's the best way, but it could be that someone wanted to be able to change the value later via refactoring tools. It would be easier and more reliable than searching for 5.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Short version:

- A constant `five` that just holds the number five is pretty useless. Don't go around making these for no reason (sometimes you have to because of syntax or typing rules, though).
- The named variables in Quaternion.cs aren't strictly necessary, but you can make the case for the code being significantly more readable with them than without.
- The named variables in ext4/resize.c aren't constants at all. They're tersely-named counters. Their names obscure their function a bit, but this code actually **does** correctly follow the project's specialized coding standards.

## What's going on with Quaternion.cs?

This one's pretty easy.

Right after this:

```
double zero = 0;
double one = 1;
```

The code does this:

```
return zero.GetHashCode() ^ one.GetHashCode();
```

Without the local variables, what does the alternative look like?

```
return 0.0.GetHashCode() ^ 1.0.GetHashCode(); // doubles, not ints!
```

What a mess! Readability is definitely on the side of creating the locals here. Moreover, I think explicitly naming the variables indicates "We've thought about this carefully" much more clearly than just writing a single confusing return statement would.

## What's going on with resize.c?

In the case of ext4/resize.c, these numbers aren't actually constants at all. If you follow the code, you'll see that they're counters and their values actually change over multiple iterations of a while loop.

[Note how they're initialized](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~baker/devices/lxr/http/source/linux/fs/ext4/resize.c#L652):

```
unsigned three = 1;
unsigned five = 5;
unsigned seven = 7;
```

Three equals one, huh? What's that about?

See, what actually happens is that `update_backups` passes these variables by reference to the function [`ext4_list_backups`](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~baker/devices/lxr/http/source/linux/fs/ext4/resize.c#L318):

```
/*
 * Iterate through the groups which hold BACKUP superblock/GDT copies in an
 * ext4 filesystem.  The counters should be initialized to 1, 5, and 7 before
 * calling this for the first time.  In a sparse filesystem it will be the
 * sequence of powers of 3, 5, and 7: 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 25, 27, 49, 81, ...
 * For a non-sparse filesystem it will be every group: 1, 2, 3, 4, ...
 */
static unsigned ext4_list_backups(struct super_block *sb, unsigned *three,
                                  unsigned *five, unsigned *seven)
```

They're counters that are preserved over the course of multiple calls. If you [look at the function body](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~baker/devices/lxr/http/source/linux/fs/ext4/resize.c#L318), you'll see that it's juggling the counters to find *the next power of 3, 5, or 7*, creating the sequence you see in the comment: 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 25, 27, &c.

Now, for the weirdest part: the variable `three` is initialized to 1 because 3<sup>0</sup> = 1. The power 0 is a special case, though, because it's the only time 3<sup>x</sup> = 5<sup>x</sup> = 7<sup>x</sup>. Try your hand at rewriting `ext4_list_backups` to work with all three counters initialized to 1 (3<sup>0</sup>, 5<sup>0</sup>, 7<sup>0</sup>) and you'll see how much more cumbersome the code becomes. Sometimes it's easier to just tell the caller to do something funky (initialize the list to 1, 5, 7) in the comments.

## So, is `five = 5` good coding style?

Is "five" a good name for the thing that the variable `five` represents in resize.c? In my opinion, it's not a style you should emulate in just any random project you take on. The simple name `five` doesn't communicate much about the purpose of the variable. If you're working on a web application or rapidly prototyping a video chat client or something and decide to name a variable `five`, you're probably going to create headaches and annoyance for anyone else who needs to maintain and modify your code.

However, **this is one example where generalities about programming don't paint the full picture**. [Take a look at the kernel's coding style document](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/CodingStyle), particularly the chapter on naming.

> GLOBAL variables (to be used only if you *really* need them) need to
>   have descriptive names, as do global functions.  If you have a function
>   that counts the number of active users, you should call that
>   "count_active_users()" or similar, you should *not* call it "cntusr()".
>
> ...
>
> LOCAL variable names should be short, and to the point.  If you have
>   some random integer loop counter, it should probably be called "i".
>   Calling it "loop_counter" is non-productive, if there is no chance of it
>   being mis-understood.  Similarly, "tmp" can be just about any type of
>   variable that is used to hold a temporary value.
>
> If you are afraid to mix up your local variable names, you have another
>   problem, which is called the function-growth-hormone-imbalance syndrome.
>   See chapter 6 (Functions).

Part of this is C-style coding tradition. Part of it is purposeful social engineering. A lot of kernel code is sensitive stuff, and it's been revised and tested many times. Since Linux is a big open-source project, it's not really hurting for contributions — in most ways, the bigger challenge is checking those contributions for quality.

Calling that variable `five` instead of something like `nextPowerOfFive` is a way to discourage contributors from meddling in code they don't understand. It's an attempt to force you to really read the code you're modifying in detail, line by line, before you try to make any changes.

Did the kernel maintainers make the right decision? I can't say. But it's clearly a purposeful move.

Comment: good answer, I was wondering about the context of the constants in that code

Comment: I'd call this an *excellent* answer. The ones that currently have more votes are certainly not wrong. They give good advice and fine reasoning. But they just regurgitate intuitive stuff that confirms the OP's suspicions. They're one level of regurgitation above "don't use magic numbers". This answer (proper credit also goes to some of the comments on the main question which head in this direction) delves deeper and really addresses the examples provided by the OP.

Comment: This answer is great. Only by reading the code can one determine if a variable is well named. The usage of `three`, `five`, and `seven` didn't inhibit Alex's understanding of the code, so what's the problem? We should code in a way that is clear to ourselves and others. If that violates coding guidelines, then the guidelines are erroneous, not the code.

Answer (score 84):

Naming numbers is terrible practice, one day something will need to change, and you'll end up with `unsigned five = 7`.

If it has some meaning, give it a meaningful name.  The 'magic number' `five` is no improvement over the magic number `5`, it's worse because it might not actually equal `5`.

This kind of thing generally arises from some cargo-cult style programming style guidelines where someone heard that "magic numbers are bad" and forbade their use without fully understanding why.

Comment: The reason I started wondering about this was because in resize.c (linux source), `unsigned three = 1;` which seems strange, then again I don't know what they're being used for in this example, and although I say they are only used once, they are actually passed by reference by another function call, so anything could be happening, kinda makes sense here now I've looked harder at the code.

Comment: It may be EVEN WORSE than this actually. Maybe if they use the magic number 5 in one spot, and they want to change it later, then changing five to be not 5 is dumb yes. But what if while the value was 5, you needed to use the magic number 5 somewhere else? So you just decided to use the same constant. Now when you change five to 7 you actually break everything.

Comment: Yep that's what I was implying, along with the fact that it is incredibly misleading, it will break any other instances.  It's an all-round disaster.

Comment: There is nothing wrong in naming a constant which will never change. like `One` `Zero` etc. Don't take me wrong I mean constants only. 1 is always going to be one, no matter what. but if an entity that may change later don't name it number. example `Decimal.One` is a constant defined in `decimal` class, because that's never gonna change.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel It does bring the question though: what is the benifit of defining a constant `1` as `ONE`?

Comment: @RichardTingle I should admit that am speechless, benefit I cant think of other than readability. That brings up a argument. Why would you ever need a `const` keyword? You could anywhere use the constant values isn't it?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Indeed, I can think of no reason anyone would ever write `constant int five = 7` (or other language variant). I has always seemed insane to me

Comment: `const` is useful for when you have *meaningful* names.  `const MaximumPrice = 7` is useful.  `const seven = 7` is not useful.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I strongly disagree that it's more readable!  What would you rather see: `if (x == OneThousandTwoHundredAndThirtyFour)` or `if (x == 1234)`?

Comment: Agreed :|. You're right. but... I guess there should be some reason to define constants like `Decimal.One` in .Net FW. I don't think designers of BCL are dumb enough to expose such constant in public API without any reason :)

Comment: @SriramSakthivel see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/745638/151019) for Decimal.One - there is more than just a constant

Comment: In any computations it is entirely necessary to prevent small mistakes (mistaking 0 for O, and 1 for l, and swapping 0 and 1) from drastically altering the meaning of the code. It also helps readability a bit.

Comment: Anyone who uses O and I for variable names deserves what they get... :P

Comment: @DeerHunter Fair point, but every reasonable programming font has `oO0` and `lI1` and `'\`"` and others purposefully made very distinct

Comment: @MrZebra: Agreed; I would go further and say anyone who uses *any* single letter for a variable name deserves what they get - two letter minimum is my rule of thumb, and that short only for extremely tight scope (like a `for` loop).

Comment: @Kos: Nope: Droid Sans Mono `O` and `0` are nearly identical. Consolas `1` and `l` are nearly identical. Especially at small sizes. And both of these are "programming" fonts.

Comment: This would make sense if `five` is more expensive than a primitive to construct. For example, the Java `BigDecimal` class has constants such as `ZERO`, `ONE`, and `TEN`. But those make sense, since they are common numbers and the constructor for the class can potentially be expensive to call (e.g. by passing in a string).

Comment: @SoftwareMonkey Poor font engineering does happen, lack of slashed 0 being the most obvious omission (Droid Sans). Ubuntu Mono and Deja Vu Sans Mono do a particularly great job of being unambiguous (like the rounded lowercase L).

Answer (score 47):

## Well named variables

Giving proper names to variables can dramatically clarify code, such as

```
constant int MAXIMUM_PRESSURE_VALUE=2;
```

This gives two key advantages:

- The value `MAXIMUM_PRESSURE_VALUE` may be used in many different places, if for whatever reason that value changes you need to change it in only one place.
- Where used it immediately shows what the function is doing, for example the following code obviously checks if the pressure is dangerously high:

  ```
  if (pressure>MAXIMUM_PRESSURE_VALUE){
      //without me telling you you can guess there'll be some safety protection in here
  }
  ```

## Poorly named variables

However, everything has a counter argument and what you have shown looks very like a good idea taken so far that it makes no sense. Defining `TWO` as 2 doesn't add any value

```
constant int TWO=2;
```

- The value `TWO` may be used in many different places, perhaps to double things, perhaps to access an index. If in the future you need to change the index you **cannot** just change to `int TWO=3;` because that would affect all the other (completely unrelated) ways you've used TWO, now you'd be tripling instead of doubling etc
- Where used it gives you no more information than if you just used "2". Compare the following two pieces of code:

  ```
  if (pressure>2){
      //2 might be good, I have no idea what happens here
  }
  ```

  or

  ```
  if (pressure>TWO){
      //TWO means 2, 2 might be good, I still have no idea what happens here
  }
  ```
- Worse still (as seems to be the case here) `TWO` may not equal 2, if so this is a form of obfuscation where the intention is to make the code less clear: obviously it achieves that.

The usual reason for this is a coding standard which forbids magic numbers but doesn't count `TWO` as a magic number; which of course it is! 99% of the time you want to use a meaningful variable name but in that 1% of the time using `TWO` instead of `2` gains you nothing (Sorry, I mean `ZERO`).

<sup>this code is inspired by Java but is intended to be language agnostic</sup>

Comment: The counter-example here is a non-primitive such as Java's `BigDecimal` class whose constructor is potentially expensive to call. Calling it once for a common value and caching the result can be beneficial.

Comment: @John O yes, if its not a primitive then all bets are off

Answer (score 11):

My organisation have certain programming guidelines, one of which is the use of magic numbers...

eg:

```
if (input == 3) //3 what? Elephants?....3 really is the magic number here...
```

This would be changed to:

```
#define INPUT_1_VOLTAGE_THRESHOLD 3u 
if (input == INPUT_1_VOLTAGE_THRESHOLD) //Not elephants :(
```

We also have a source file with -200,000 -> 200,000 #defined in the format:

```
#define MINUS_TWO_ZERO_ZERO_ZERO_ZERO_ZERO -200000
```

which can be used in place of magic numbers, for example when referencing a specific index of an array.

I imagine this has been done for "Readability".

Comment: First example is great for showing why you would 'name' a number.  The 2nd though?  I can't see how that helps anyone anywhere!

Comment: @cjb110 It may not help, however it saves time having to define every number when you need it. We simply include the file, and hey presto, 400,000 #defines done. Tbh, it was just to save time in the long run.

Comment: TWELVE_VOLTS makes perfect sense to me, and i do the same thing myself, but your example is not `if (input == twelve)` which if the bit I was struggling to understand :p

Comment: Uh, what? `TWELVE_VOLTS` is defined on a project-by-project basis?  So `TWELVE_VOLTS` might actually represent, say, 13V?  If so, that's horrible.  What would make your code more readable (and less error-prone) is if it was clear what units your *variables* represented; e.g. `if (inputVolts == 12)`.

Comment: Not quite, project A might need "input" to be TWELVE_VOLTS, but project B would need it to be THIRTEEN_VOLTS. However, i do like your suggestion of "inputVolts" over "input".

Comment: This example is confusing. The two big reasons for not having magic numbers are readability and ability to easily and safely alter code. "Twelve volts" is about as descriptive as "12", so the first concern has not been satisfied. It would be bizarre to expect "twelve volts" to mean anything other than twelve volts, so the second concern is also not addressed. A "constant" like this is as good as a magic number (in fact worse, because it adds complexity). It should be called `inputVoltage` - which brings us back to the original question.

Comment: Having `TWELVE_VOLTS` in one project and `THIRTEEN_VOLTS` in another is silly; those constants have no semantic meaning.  In a sane system, you'd have a constant named something like `INPUT_VOLTAGE` and set it differently for different projects.  There's some sarcasm in your answer, but I'm afraid that some people will misinterpret it and think that you're advocating this sort of horrible practice.

Comment: I should probably explain this a little better, coming from an embedded control system background, i would normally define 12 as "INPUT_1_THRESHOLD".

Comment: This is horrible. The correct way is to either name your variable a quantity which implies voltage as units, or/and define a Voltage integer type (this last one might not be reasonable for low-level languages like C, but for instance in C# you could that fairly easily and have the `ToString()` method append a `V` at the end of the voltage representation and you don't get much more self-documenting than that). I won't even comment on the `MINUS_TWO_ZERO_ZERO_ZERO_ZERO_ZERO` macro, I died a little inside reading it.

Comment: @Thomas whats wrong with the MINUS_TWO_ZERO_ZERO_ZERO_ZERO_ZERO?

Comment: @Joshpbarron What’s wrong with it is that it serves literally no purpose at all. The symbol "2" is replaced with the symbol "TWO", they both have exactly the same meaning so are 100% equivalent. On the other hand your first example is an example of exactly what *should* be done to avoided magic numbers; give a meaningful name to a value

Comment: Understood, however what about accessing an index of an array? 
Should i have Names[1], Names[ONE] or Names[INDEX_1]?

Comment: @Joshpbarron It makes no difference. Usually you would want a meaningful name, but assuming there isn't one (which happens occasionally) you might as well use `Names[1]`. I've expanded on this a little in my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22042928/2187042)

Comment: `ONE` is just as much of a magic number as `1`

Comment: @RichardTingle It might even be more magic, when it doesn't do what you expect it to.

Comment: "We also have a source file with -200,000 -> 200,000 #defined.." That's wrong on multiple levels. I would fire whoever thought of that, and whoever used it.

Answer (score 7):

The numbers 0, 1, ... are integers. Here, the 'named variables' give the integer a different type. It might be more reasonable to specify these constant (const unsigned five = 5;)

Comment: I see, so instead of writing `return 1f;` or `return 1L;` you would `float one = 1; return one;` or `long one = 1; return one;`

Answer (score 7):

I've used something akin to that a couple times to write values to files:

```
const int32_t zero = 0 ;

fwrite( &zero, sizeof(zero), 1, myfile );
```

fwrite accepts a const pointer, but if some function needs a non const pointer, you'll end up using a non const variable.

P.S.: That always keeps me wondering what may be the sizeof zero .

Comment: Okay, I have to admit, this is actually legitimate usage.  However, any variables you name in this way should have a narrow scope, and the actual cases where you'd want to use a name like `zero` instead of a more meaningful name are rather limited.

Comment: +1 - this is exactly what the [resize.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/ext3/resize.c) mentioned in the question is doing - see line 398.  Predictably, the code's already run amock - line 391 has `unsigned three = 1;`.

Comment: @TonyD 3^0 = 1. I guess it would've been more consistent to start all three counters at 1, but three = 1, five = 5, seven = 7 is a trivial optimization that makes sense in the context of the count-by-powers trick that it's doing.

Answer (score 6):

How do you come to a conslusion that it is used only once? It is public, it could be used any number of times from any assembly.

```
public static readonly Quaternion Zero = new Quaternion();
public static readonly Quaternion One = new Quaternion(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
```

Same thing applies to .Net framework `decimal` class. which also exposes public constants like this.

```
public const decimal One = 1m;
public const decimal Zero = 0m;
```

Comment: I come to that conclusion because I was looking at the code. `private static int GetIdentityHashCode()
        {
            // This code is called only once.
            double zero = 0;
            double one = 1;
            // return zero.GetHashCode() ^ zero.GetHashCode() ^ zero.GetHashCode() ^ one.GetHashCode();
            // But this expression can be simplified because the first two hash codes cancel.
            return zero.GetHashCode() ^ one.GetHashCode();
        }`

Comment: @Jack0x539 in your example you can't say `1.GetHashCode()`

Comment: @Jack0x539 if it is a local variable there is no good reason to do that other than readability. I often do that but here it is a local variable I'll probably declare it as `const`

Comment: @concept3d You can do that, try it out :)

Answer (score 6):

Numbers are often given a name when these numbers have special meaning.

For example in the Quaternion case the identity quaternion and unit length quaternion have special meaning and are frequently used in a special context. Namely Quaternion with (0,0,0,1) is an identity quaternion so it's a common  practice to define them instead of using magic numbers.

For example

```
// define as static 
static Quaternion Identity = new Quaternion(0,0,0,1);


Quaternion Q1 = Quaternion.Identity;
//or 
if ( Q1.Length == Unit ) // not considering floating point error
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but do think it unfair to assume it's a "hater".  This question is specifically about cases where the constant doesn't add abstraction and isn't obviously useful; this answer does nothing to address that scenario.  I don't understand all the answers explaining the generally accepted best practice (or why they've attracted upvotes) - it's the seeming exception that's of interest.

Answer (score 2):

One of my first programming jobs was on a PDP 11 using Basic. The Basic interpreter allocated memory to every number required, so every time the program mentioned 0, a byte or two would be used to store the number 0. Of course back in those days memory was a lot more limited than today and so it was important to conserve.

Every program in that work place started with:

```
10  U0%=0
20  U1%=1
```

That is, for those who have forgotten their Basic:

```
Line number 10: create an integer variable called U0 and assign it the number 0
Line number 20: create an integer variable called U1 and assign it the number 1
```

These variables, by local convention, never held any other value, so they were effectively constants. They allowed 0 and 1 to be used throughout the program without wasting any memory.

Aaaaah, the good old days!

Answer (score 1):

some times it's more readable to write:

```
double pi=3.14; //Constant or even not constant
...
CircleArea=pi*r*r;
```

instead of:

```
CircleArea=3.14*r*r;
```

and may be you would use `pi` more again (you are not sure but you think it's possible later or in other classes if they are public)

and then if you want to change `pi=3.14` into `pi=3.141596` it's easier.

and some other like `e=2.71`, `Avogadro` and etc.

Comment: Far more readable for mathematical constants such as PI yes, and you don't want to be typing out 10 digits every time, I know that, but it was the usage in the examples that I gave that I did not understand the value of.

Comment: @Jack0x539 As I noted in my comment to your question, the reason is not "don't want to type out 10 digits". It's impossible to actually type out pi, so you must settle on some approximate form - and it cannot be conclusively decided how many digits is the right amount of precision, so you must allow for changing precision later. Technically the constant called `pi` is not actually pi but an approximation - hence, unlike pi, this so-called `pi` is not necessarily constant between compilations.