# Confusing Logical Operators in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, conditional-statements, logical-operators

I am working with a legacy code base written in VB and have run into a conditional operator that I don't understand and cannot figure out what to search for to resolve it.

What I am dealing with is the following code and the variables that result as true. The specific parts that I do not understand are (1) the relationship between the first `X` and the first parens `(-2` and (2) the role of `X < 2`

- If `X` is a value below `-2` it evaluates as `false`.
- If `X` is a value above `2` it evaluates as `true`.
- If `Y` is below `5` it evaluates to `true` as expected.

---

```vb
X = 3
Y = 10

If X > (-2 And X < 2) Or Y < 5 Then
    'True
Else
    'False
End If
```

Comment: Not sure exactly what's going on (hence just a comment), but I'd bet the trick here relies on the fact that `And` is a _bitwise_ operator, rather than a straight conditional operator.  Given any excuse I'd re-write it to be easier to understand how it follows the spec. The existing code might be faster than something that's easier to understand, but I doubt this expression is driving your application's performance in a meaningful way.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn - I definitely agree with re-writing it as well is it not being crucial to performance. Unfortunately, I don't know the original intention of the logical operators in this particular part of the code base, hence attempting to figure out what it could be trying to solve for :/

Comment: You are comparing an Integer to a Boolean.  And a Boolean to an Integer.  That gives the compiler a headache that it needs to sort out.  With perhaps the somewhat surprising result that True equals -1.  Which was a fairly brilliant move that ensures that the And and Or operators can work both as bitwise and logical operators.  Really rather best to not give the compiler a headache and it won't give you one either.

Comment: **Can you make sure that the output is *indeed* the desired one?** I don't have any proof to back this up, but I have a feeling, *just a feeling* that there's a typo in this code, where the original intention was to simply write `If (X > -2 And X <2) Or Y < 5`, and no bitwise operations were meant to be involved, hence this can be optimized by replacing `And` & `Or` with `AndAlso` & `OrElse`. Perhaps we can find an evidence to prove *or refute* this if you can provide more context.

Answer (score 5):

I'm gonna leave off the `Or Y < 5` part of the expression for this post as uninteresting, and limit myself to the `X > (-2 And X < 2)` side of the expression.

I haven't done much VB over the last several years, so I started out with some digging into Operator Precedence rules in VB, to be sure I have things right. I found definitive info on VBA and VB.Net, and some MSDN stuff that might have been VB6 but could also have been the 2013 version of VB.Net. All of them, though, gave the `<` and `>` comparison operators higher precedence over the `And` operator, regardless of whether you see `And` as logical or bitwise.

With that info, and also knowing that we must look inside parentheses first, I'm now confident the very first part of the expression to be evaluated is `X < 2` (rather than `-2 And X`). Further, we know this will produce a Boolean result, and this Boolean result must be then converted to an Integer to do a *bitwise* (**not** logical)  `And` with `-2`. That result (I'll call it `n`), which is still an Integer, can at last be compared to see if `X > n`, which will yield the final result of the expression as a Boolean.

I did some more digging and found [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/745366/3043) about converting VB Booleans to Integers. While not definitive documentation, I was once privileged to meet the author (Hi @JaredPar) and know he worked on the VB compiler team at Microsoft, so he should know what he's talking about. It indicates that VB Boolean `True` has the surprising value of `-1` as an integer! `False` becomes the more-normal `0`.

At this point we need to talk about the binary representation of negative numbers. Using [this reference](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/544990/Understand-how-bitwise-operators-work-Csharp-and-V) as a guide (I do vaguely remember learning about this in college, but it's not the kind of thing I need every day), I'm going to provide a conversion table for integers from -3 to +3 in an imaginary integer size of only 4 bits (short version: invert the bit pattern and add one to get the negative representation):

```
-3   1101
-2   1110
-1   1111 --this helps explain **why** -1 was used for True
 0   0000
 1   0001
 2   0010
 3   0010
```

Stepping back, let's now consider the original `-2 And X < 2` parenthetical and look at the results from the True (-1) and False (0) possible outcomes for `X < 2` after a bitwise `And` with `-2`:

```
-2 (1110) And True  (1111) = 1110 = -2
-2 (1110) And False (0000) = 0000 =  0
```

Really the whole point here from using the `-1` bit pattern is  **anything** `And True` produces that same thing you started with, whereas anything `And False` produces all zeros.

So if `X < 2` you get `True`, which results in `-2`; otherwise you end up with `0`. It's interesting to note here that if our language used positive one for `True`, you'd end up with the same `0000` value doing a bitwise `And` with `-2` that you get from `False` (`1110 And 0001`).

Now we know enough to look at some values for `X` and determine the result of the entire original expression. Any positive integer is greater than both `-2` and `0`, so the expression should result in `True`. Zero and -1 are similar: they are less than two, and so will be compared again only as greater than -2 and thus always result in `True`. Negative two, though, and anything below, should be `False`.

Unfortunately, this means you could simplify the entire expression down to `X > -2`. Either I'm wrong about operator precedence, my reference for negative integer bit patterns is wrong, you're using a version of VB that converts `True` to something other than `-1`, or this code is just ***way*** over-complicated from the get-go.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the sequence is as follows:

r = -2 and X 'outputs X with the least significant bit set to 0 (meaning the first lesser even number)

r = (r < 2) 'outputs -1 or 0

r = (X > r) 'outputs -1 or 0

r = r Or (Y < 5)

Use AndAlso and OrElse.