# Realize XNOR gate using AND, OR and NOT gates

Tags: vb.net, vb6, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

As the title says, I'm trying to realize an `XNOR` gate using the following three gates: `AND`, `OR`, `NOT`.

Here's the way I did it:
`TextBox1.Text = (a And b) Or (Not a And Not b)`

The following code gives me an output of `-5`, when the expected output is `11` for the input `a = 10`, `b = 14`.

I'm trying to understand what I'm doing wrong - my `XOR` gate works fine, `XNOR` doesn't.

Comment: My answer to this question may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46330587/confusing-logical-operators-in-vb-net

Comment: Regarding your first comment, my `XOR` gate seems to work fine, so I doubt it's VB acting up. Anyway, when I insert `10` and `14` as arguments into an online `XNOR` 'calculator', I get 11 as output. Could you elaborate why my program outputs `-5`?

Comment: `dim xnor = (a And b) Or (Math.Abs(Not a) And Math.Abs(Not b))`

Comment: Thanks Jimi. Why does that work and mine doesn't?

Comment: It's just a simplified way to *not* consider the sign.

Comment: Can you clarify if you are using VB6 or VB.net? They are not the same language (although maybe the answer to this particular question would be the same for either)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's work through this by hand. For simplicity I'll start with a "reduced" 4-bit integer. So let's look at our initial bits:

```
a = 10 = 1010
b = 14 = 1110
```

And now substitute in the parts of the full expression:

```
a AND b 
1010 & 1110 = 1010

Not a = 0101
Not b = 0001

Not a And Not b
0101 & 0001 = 0001
```

The full thing:

```
(a And b) Or (Not a And Not b)

1010 | 0001 = 1011
```

So we have `1011` as the result.

This *looks like* an `11` at first, but we're forgetting something important: we're not using unsigned integers. We need to allow for negative values and answer the important question whether this is a negative or a positive value.

For negative values, we represent the bits using information from [this guide](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/544990/Understand-how-bitwise-operators-work-Csharp-and-V) (short version: invert the bit pattern and add 1 to convert a positive number to negative, invert the process -- subtract one first -- to convert negative to positive).

The result is if it's positive, it's `11`. But if it's negative, it's `-5`. Hmm.... wait a minute. Those values look familiar! But which is correct?

To find out, let's try this again with a five-bit integer.

```
a = 10 = 01010
b = 14 = 01110
```

Substitute in the parts of the full expression:

```
a AND b 
01010 & 01110 = 01010

Not a = 10101
Not b = 10001

Not a And Not b
10101 & 10001 = 10001
```

The full thing:

```
(a And b) Or (Not a And Not b)

01010 | 10001 = 11011
```

*This is a new bit pattern!* `11` no longer makes sense at all (we'd have `27` instead). However, treated as a negative value, *we still get `-5`.* Moreover, as we keep adding bits to our integer the bits will always result in `1`s added to left in the final bit pattern. However, this pattern will still always produce `-5` no matter how many bits we add, where the original `11` will keep getting larger. Finally, there is this excerpt from my earlier link:

> How you can be sure this number is negative? ... If the first bit is a 1, the number is negative.

Because we have a leading `1`, the number should be treated as negative, meaning `-5` is the correct result of the code.

What happened is **the 4-bit value hid this by effectively overflowing our integer.** If we have to allow for negative values, 4 bits only goes to ±7. But I wanted to show the 4-bit version first, to show the 11/-5 split.

Finally, let's look at the correct expression (using a 5-bit integer again):

```
(a And b) Or (Math.Abs(Not a) And Math.Abs(Not b))

a = 10 = 01010
b = 14 = 01110
```

Substitute in the parts of the full expression:

```
a AND b 
01010 & 01110 = 01010

Not a = 10101
Not b = 10001

Math.Abs(Not a) = 01011 ' Subtract 1, invert pattern
Math.Abs(Not b) = 01111

Math.Abs(Not a) And Math.Abs(Not b) 
01011 & 01111 = 01011
```

The full thing:

```
(a And b) Or (Not a And Not b)

01010 | 01011 = 01011
```

And this finally produces the expected `11`.