# VB Radiobutton.checked state returns -1 when performed arithmetic operations with it

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, radio-button

I am a beginner in visual basic, I am developing a calculator in which i have the following piece of code.

`labeltotal.text = (radiobutton1.Checked) * 1000`

My expectation from the above code is that , if the radiobutton1 is checked , the value of the total should be 1000  otherwise it should be 0.

But what i am getting is , if radiobutton1 is checked, total value changes to -1000 otherwise it goes to 0.

But if i use checkbox , i get correct values. For example,
`labeltotal.text = (checkbox1.Checkstate) * 1000` 
it givse me correct values as expected depending on the checkstate.

How can i make the radio button to behave the same way as checkbox in above code?

Comment: VB?  VB.Net? VBA?  Which one?  The first thing to learn is that they are similar, but not the same.  :-)

Comment: it is visual basic .

Comment: ok, you should probably remove the [tag:VBA] tag.  Also, check out the [tour] as well as [ask] and [mcve].  Oh, and, Welcome to Stack Overflow!  :-)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you should switch `Option Strict` to `On`.

If a `Boolean` is converted to `Integer`, you'll get `-1` for `True` and `0` for `False`.

For further information see: [Convert Boolean to Integer in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/745292/convert-boolean-to-integer-in-vb-net)

So one of the following should return the result you want:

```
labeltotal.Text = (CInt(radiobutton1.Checked) * 1000 * -1).ToString

labeltotal.Text = (CInt(radioButton1.Checked) ^ 2 * 1000).ToString
```

---

There's also the function `Convert.ToInt32` which will return a `1` for `True`:

```
labeltotal.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(radioButton1.Checked) * 1000).ToString
```

But in this specific case, calculation does not really make sense.

The following is more clear and fits better for this case:

```
labeltotal.Text = If(radioButton1.Checked, "1000", "0")
```