# How to set items check in checklistbox?

Tags: vb.net, listboxitems, checklistbox

I use SetItemChecked method to automatically check the checklistbox but it does not work. Anyone have a look to my code and please give a solution?

```
Private Sub Check(value As Double)
    If 0 <= value < 20 Then
        Me.CheckedListBox1.SetItemChecked(0, True)
    ElseIf 20 <= value < 40 Then
        Me.CheckedListBox1.SetItemChecked(1, True)
    ElseIf 40 <= value < 60 Then
        Me.CheckedListBox1.SetItemChecked(2, True)
    ElseIf 60 <= value < 80 Then
        Me.CheckedListBox1.SetItemChecked(3, True)
    Else
        Me.CheckedListBox1.SetItemChecked(4, True)
    End If
End Sub
```

Then I call check(60) and it returns the 1st item check. It is wrong?

Comment: Change your condition  Me.CheckedListBox1.ClearSelected()
        If 0 <= value And value < 20 Then
            Me.CheckedListBox1.SetItemChecked(0, True)
        ElseIf 20 <= value And value  < 40 Then
            Me.CheckedListBox1.SetItemChecked(1, True)
        ElseIf 40 <= value  And value < 60 Then
            Me.CheckedListBox1.SetItemChecked(2, True)
        ElseIf 60 <= value And value< 80 Then
            Me.CheckedListBox1.SetItemChecked(3, True)
        Else
            Me.CheckedListBox1.SetItemChecked(4, True)
        End If

Comment: It is pretty wrong, doesn't "return" anything, doesn't uncheck items and ought to use radio buttons, but not wrong as described.  Set a breakpoint and single-step the code.

Comment: There should be a close-vote-reason "use the debugger"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to correct your conditions as shown below also Clear

```
Private Sub Check(value As Double)
        Me.CheckedListBox1.ClearSelected()
        If 0 <= value And value < 20 Then
            Me.CheckedListBox1.SetItemChecked(0, True)
        ElseIf 20 <= value And value  < 40 Then
            Me.CheckedListBox1.SetItemChecked(1, True)
        ElseIf 40 <= value  And value < 60 Then
            Me.CheckedListBox1.SetItemChecked(2, True)
        ElseIf 60 <= value And value< 80 Then
            Me.CheckedListBox1.SetItemChecked(3, True)
        Else
            Me.CheckedListBox1.SetItemChecked(4, True)
        End If
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The first `If`-statement will always evaluate to `True`.
Because `True` is converted to `1` and `False` is converted to `0`.

It's getting clearer if you look at this:

```
If (0 <= value) < 20 Then
```

So no matter which number is contained in `value`, the condition will be either...

- `True < 20`
  ..or...
- `False < 20`

For more information see here: [Convert Boolean to Integer in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/745292/convert-boolean-to-integer-in-vb-net)

---

So you need to change the conditions like following:

```
If 0 <= value And value < 20 Then ...
```

Comment: Thanks all guys for your answers. I handle the problems. Thanks MatSnow, ChiragMM. your code is work pretty well.