# How to convert a LINQ statement from VB to C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq

I have the following LINQ statement in VB:

```
Dim query As List(Of RepresentativeCase)
query = (From w In Me.RepresentativeCases
            Where w.Active = True
            Group w By w.PublicSubType, w.LawArea Into g = Group
            Where g.Count(Function(x) x.PublicSubType.Distinct.Count) >= 100
            Select g.First()
        ).ToList()
```

I am trying to convert into C# and having trouble.  I got the following but it doesn't compile:

```
List<RepresentativeCase> query = (
    from w in this.RepresentativeCases
    where w.Active == true
    group w by new { w.PublicSubType, w.LawArea} into g
    let PublicSubType = g.Key.PublicSubType
    let LawArea = g.Key.LawArea
    where g.Count(x => x.PublicSubType.Distinct().Count()) > 100 // breaks here
    select g.First()).ToList();
```

The `where g.Count(x => x.PublicSubType.Distinct().Count()) > 100` line won't compile. Additionally, I am confused by the `Into g = Group` in the VB sample - not clear what it does.

What am I missing?

Comment: What's the compile-time error message?

Comment: Turn `Option Strict On` in VB and it will not compile there too, like it should.

Comment: @Flydog57 https://i.imgur.com/s808bPq.png

Comment: @GSerg Right, but how do I convert it to C#?

Comment: Fix the error in VB so that it compiles with Option Strict On, mirror that in C#.

Comment: Just a matter of style,  *Where w.Active = True* can be *Where w.Active*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```vb
Where g.Count(Function(x) x.PublicSubType.Distinct.Count) >= 100
```

would only compile with `Option Strict Off`. The outer `Count` call requires a delegate that returns a `Boolean`, but the inner `Count` call is returning an `Integer`. That means that that `Integer` must be implicitly converted to a `Boolean`.

The question you should have been asking was how to fix that VB to compile with `Option Strict On` and, to work that out, you should be considering what the code is actually doing. What's actually happening is that a count of zero will be converted to `False` and any other count will be converted to `True`. That means that what that code is actually doing is determining whether there are any items in the `PublicSubType` list. What's the proper way to do that? With the `Any` method:

```vb
Where g.Count(Function(x) x.PublicSubType.Any()) >= 100
```

Note that the `Distinct` call is pointless because it might change the number of items but not whether there are any items or not.

It should be pretty obvious how to convert that to C# but, so that I am answering the specific question as asked:

```cs
List<RepresentativeCase> query = (
    from w in this.RepresentativeCases
    where w.Active == true
    group w by new { w.PublicSubType, w.LawArea} into g
    let PublicSubType = g.Key.PublicSubType
    let LawArea = g.Key.LawArea
    where g.Count(x => x.PublicSubType.Any()) > 100
    select g.First()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

In this line:

```
 Where g.Count(Function(x) x.PublicSubType.Distinct.Count) >= 100
```

The outer `.Count()` method is expecting a lambda that returns a **Boolean**, where the result tells `.Count()` whether or not to include this item as part of the final result. But you have this:

```
Function(x) x.PublicSubType.Distinct.Count
```

The result of the above function is an **Integer**, not a Boolean. Also, you should write it (probably) like this:

```
Function(x) x.PublicSubType.Distinct().Count()
```

It is still legal to omit parentheses when calling methods in VB.Net, but this is for backwards compatibility with old code and is *not recommended* in other situations.

I'm not sure what the VB code is doing here, but with a sane configuration that would not compile in VB, either. What you have is **not sane**, especially as [VB has some weird ideas about what Integer values can map to Boolean true and false.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/745366/3043)

Comment: I don't think that that last link is relevant because that's more about converting `Boolean` to `Integer` than `Integer` to `Boolean`. `CBool(1)`, `CBool(-1)`, `Convert.ToBoolean(1)` and `Convert.ToBoolean(-1)` all produce `True`. The difference is in `CInt(True)` and `Convert.ToInt32(True)`, which produce -1 and 1 respectively.