# VB.NET How to check if username and password textboxes are not empty?

Tags: vb.net

is there a way to check two textboxes (username, password) to have text? I'd like to check that before connect buttons gets enabled.

i tried to use two if-statements like

```
if not user.text = "" then
buttonlogin.enabled = true
end if

if not password.text = "" then
buttonlogin.enabled = true
end if
```

but the button gets enabled if one of them gets text instead of both.

Comment: The following may be of interest: [String.IsNullOrEmpty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.isnullorempty?view=net-8.0)

Comment: Set the computer aside, get a pen and paper, then read through your code and write down what happens in each step of your code.

Answer (score 3):

Do it like this:

```vb
ButtonLogin.Enabled = Not (String.IsNullOrWhitespace(User.Text) OrElse String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Password.Text))
```

This does four things not yet shown in other answers:

1. Assigns the boolean expression result directly to the button's  `.Enabled` property, as a single line of code... no `If`/`Else` conditional expressions needed.
2. Uses the correct [`IsNullOrWhitespace()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.isnullorwhitespace?view=net-8.0) method to check the textbox values. Other answers (except one) would allow me to click the button just by putting a space or tab character (or similar) into the textbox. Even the answer with `.Trim()` may leave certain whitespace behind (vertical tab is one example, along with certain other unicode characters). Not that `IsNullOrWhitespace()` is perfect, but it performs a little better and correctly captures intent.
3. Uses [DeMorgan's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) to factor out the negation (we only need one `Not` operation)
4. Uses a proper short-circuiting logical boolean operator ([`OrElse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/orelse-operator), in this case). The other answers use the older VB operators, which are actually *bitwise* operators rather than true logical operators. Among other things, the bitwise operators do not short circuit and can [sometimes be a little odd](https://stackoverflow.com/a/745366/3043)... better to use the real logical operators most of the time.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe like this.

```
    If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(user.Text) Or String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(password.Text) Then
    MessageBox.Show("Please fill in both textboxes.", "Validation Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
Else
    ' Both textboxes have content.
    ' Your code logic here...
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

```
If not user.text = "" And not password.text = ""  Then

    buttonlogin.enabled = true

Else

    buttonlogin.enabled = false
End If
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score -2):

Try

```
if string.IsNullOrEmpty(strings.trim(user.text)) then
     buttonlogin.enable = false
else
     buttonlogin.enable = true
end if
```

and same for password.