# Logical AND in Forth?

Tags: keyword, logical-operators, forth

I know the AND word defines binary `and`... but what defines logical `and`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The *same* word, `AND`, is also used for logical *and*. But the two input values to `AND` are recommended to be **well-formed flags**; **true** and **false** are represented by two values, bits all set (-1) and bits all unset (0). Other values than these may work as true (as in C), but it may lead to subtle errors.

All comparison operators return well-formed flags, but for instance `-` does not. The following evaluates to false (0).

```
7 5 - 7 3 - AND
```

`AND` gets bit patterns 100 and 010. The result is 0 (as it does the bitwise *and*).

References:

1. [Bit Manipulations in Forth](http://www.forth.org/svfig/Len/bits.htm), part of *Learning Forth Bit by Bit*.
2. Section "A Little Logic" in [Chapter 4](http://home.iae.nl/users/mhx/sf4/sf4.html) of *Starting Forth*.

Comment: Don't know enough forth to say if this is valid, but the bit patterns 0xFF00 and 0x00FF have bitwise and 0x0000 but logical and True (since both are nonzero)

Comment: @TokenMacGuy: Thanks! It was such an example I was looking for. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The Forth AND is a bit-wise AND on 64 bit values. Of course these operators work okay with masks. But if these values are all ones or all zeroes, the result is also all ones or all zeroes (the same is true for bit-wise OR and XOR INVERT operations.).

A boolean flag in Forth is all ones or all zeroes. So if the inputs are boolean flags, the output of AND OR XOR INVERT are also booleans and those operators can thus be used to represent boolean operators. Please note that operations like = < 0= result in a boolean flag.

The situation is the same with +. Because integers are defined as two-complement, + (plus) can be used for signed as well as unsigned numbers. So there is no separate name for unsigned addition of integers.