# Why does Forth return -1 as a flag for True?

Tags: forth

The Forth code

```
7 3 > . (7 > 3)
```

returns `-1`, but every other language I've ever used uses `1` as a flag for true. Why is this? What accounts for this difference?

Comment: My guess is that it's a wish to have `TRUE` be the bitwise inversion of `FALSE`.

Comment: C uses non-zero as true, not 1. Never used it?

Comment: @EJP C's *tests* accept non-zero as true.  So do Forth's tests.  C's canonically true value, as returned by comparison operators, is 1.  Forth's is -1.

Comment: Related: *[Logical AND in Forth?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3873456)*

Answer (score 20, accepted):

-1 is all bits set which then has the benefit that words such as `and`, `or`, `not`, ... serve as *both* logical and bitwise operators (as opposed to say C with `&&`, `||`, `!`, ... vs. `&`, `|`, `~`, ...)

Comment: This is the actual, correct answer to the OP's question.  It also allows the host CPU to make branch-free decisions using AND and OR instead of multiplication and addition.  E.g., P1 A1 AND P2 A2 AND OR, if Px are predicates and Ax are the corresponding answers, versus its equivalent in C, A1*P1 + A2*P2.  Other languages also used -1 for true (BASIC, PL/I, etc.), so C was in the minority at the time.  Think of it as a "signed boolean."

Answer (score 5):

Per [the 1994 standard](http://www.forth.org/svfig/Win32Forth/DPANS94.txt):

> Flags Flags may have one of two logical states, true or false. 
>   Programs that use flags as arithmetic operands have an environmental
>   dependency. A true flag returned by a standard word shall be a
>   single-cell value with all bits set.  A false flag returned by a
>   standard word shall be a single-cell value with all bits clear.

So `true` is not `-1`, it's all bits set — the logical opposite of no bits set. In your particular environment, all bits set is `-1`, presumably because your computer uses two's complement arithmetic. But it doesn't have to in order to run Forth and therefore `true` doesn't have to be `-1`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23838410/interrupts-instruction-pointer-and-instruction-queue-in-8086

Comment: I read that bit from the documentation about flags before I came to stack overflow, but I was missing the bit about two's complement. So 11111111 comes out as -1 in 2's complement. Every machine that I've used Forth with has returned -1, but you're saying it's conceivable that some computer out there is going to return 255? What kind of computer wouldn't use two's compliment under these circumstances?

Comment: Apparently Unisys still sells 36-bit word, 1's complement UNIVAC mainframes but I can't find anything else that isn't now 2's complement.

Answer (score 0):

It is because all processors have a branch-if-zero instruction and not branch if all one's.

So if you want a construct like this:

```
test IF (some code) ELSE (other code) THEN
```

you are going to use a branch to reach the (other code) part. This branch will be a branch if zero so this implies that 0 is a false flag and the contrary will be

```
0 NOT
```

which is all one's so it means true.