# Are negative boolean values defined?

Tags: c

In C, at least every positive value except for 0 is treated as a boolean true. But what about a negative value? I did some tests and it seems that also negative values are treated as a boolean true. Is this a defined behaviour or implementation specific?

(I came to think about this when I saw in a question, someone promoting declaring "true" and "false" in an enum as 1 and 0.)

Comment: Everything that is not `false` is `true`?

Comment: i think this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/727196/boolean-true-positive-1-or-negative-1 would answer your question

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is defined behavior. I'll look for the C99 standard paragraph stating as such

> **§ 6.3.1.2**
>   When any scalar value is converted to _Bool, the result is 0 if
>   the value compares equal to 0;
>   otherwise, the result is 1.

Comment: +1 The standard `bool` is good. I use an `enum` as a fallback in case a particular compiler lacks C99 support.

Answer (score 2):

I believe 0 is false and everything else is true.

See @casper's reply here: [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/727196/boolean-true-positive-1-or-negative-1)

> I would take a hint from C here, where false is defined absolutely as 0, and true is defined as not false. This is an important distinction, when compared to an absolute value for true. Unless you have a type that only has two states, you have to account for all values within that value type, what is true, and what is false.

Answer (score 2):

This is the correct behavior, in C **0** is **False** and **everything else** is **True**

Answer (score 1):

In C, there is no boolean type; 0 and 0.0f are considered "false" in boolean contexts, everything else is "true".

Declaring "true" and "false" in an enum is wrong, because then the following code will break:

```
if (2 == TRUE)
```

(2 should evaluate as "true", but if TRUE has been defined as 1, the two values aren't considered equal).

Comment: Anyone testing if a value is equal to `true` is wrong, as the test shouldn't be being made in the first place. An `enum` is fine in certain situations.

Comment: There is a boolean type in C99, see my answer

Comment: Being a nitpick here, but the enum, when used, looks like a proper boolean type but doesn't behave like one. That's why I prefer not to have it in the first place, and just use 0 and 1 instead.

Comment: Fair enough. I wouldn't write `if(x == true)` even if it were a proper boolean type. I just like to have a functional boolean type to return from functions sometimes.

Answer (score -1):

C defines 0 as false and everything else as true. Positive, negative, whatever.

I believe I recently advocated the use of `typedef enum { false, true } bool;` so I'll own up to it. (If my original code didn't have a `typedef` involved, that was an error of judgement on my part.) All nonzero values are true, so I wouldn't advocate using an enumerated `bool` type for things like this:

```
if(x == true) // not what you want
if(!x == false) // works, but why so much effort?
```

I generally perfer simply `if(x)` or `if(!x)` to explicit tests against boolean values. However, sometimes it's good to have a boolean type:

```
bool is_something(int x)
{ // assume for the sake of an argument that the test is reasonably complex
    if(/* something */) return false;
    if(/* something else */) return true;
    return false;
}
```

This is no better than having the type be `int`, but at least you're being explicit with what the result is meant for.

Also, as per someone else above, a better `bool` might be:

```
typedef enum { false, true = !false } bool;
```

I believe `!` is guaranteed to return 0 or 1, but I could be wrong, and the above works well either way.

Comment: Just don't do that. `bool`, `true` and `false` are defined in "stdbool.h" and do the right thing.

Comment: @Jens - Not all systems will have C99 support, maybe someone's compiler is really old or is made by Microsoft, and it's so easy to define a fill-in `bool` type in case someone doesn't have one that if you're going to use a `bool` type in the first place you might as well have a backup.

Comment: Then you'd better do how it is foreseen in C89, namely to have `int` for Boolean values. And define your replacement in a separate file that defines them as macros `bool == int`, `false == 0` and `true == 1`. Otherwise, once you'd have a C99 compiler, this would be a real pain to port.

Comment: @Jens - Disagree. I don't think it matters whether you define them as macros or as an `enum` so long as you define it to work the same, use it consistently (i.e. make no assumptions about the value of `true`, don't test non-`bool` values against `bool` values, etc.), and define it conditionally for anything not supporting C99, there's no way it won't work. And `bool` isn't tremendously useful anyway, so even if something breaks, it can't really break too badly.