# Form ComboBox value, true=-1?

Tags: excel, vba, forms, boolean

Given a simple form, with a multi-column combobox, that gets filled using the code below.
Does anyone know why the form returns "-1" instead of "1" for TRUE?

[image]

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    loadCellInfoTest
End sub
   Sub loadCellInfoTest()
        With cbxBreakdown
            .Clear
            .ColumnCount = 4
            .ColumnWidths = "70,110,70,600"
            '.value = "Breakdown for: " & targetFormula

            'HEADERS
            .AddItem "Sheet"
            .List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = "Address"
            .List(.ListCount - 1, 2) = "Value"
            .List(.ListCount - 1, 3) = "Formula"

            .AddItem "test"
            .List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = "Address"
            .List(.ListCount - 1, 2) = True  'THIS RETURNS -1
            .List(.ListCount - 1, 3) = "Formula"
        End With
    End Sub
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/727196/boolean-true-positive-1-or-negative-1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `True` is a boolean that converts to `-1`.

In VBA by definition:

- `True = -1`
- `False = 0`

In formulas:

- `True = 1`
- `False = 0`

If you want it as text:

```
.List(.ListCount - 1, 2) = "True"
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I've solved the the issue by defining the variable in which i load the value as String. I'm loading a cell value in the combo-box, and that cell can either have a formula, or be the target of a checkbox.

Comment: `cStr(True)` converts it into string too.